# Save new form's Items created in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, buttonclick

I have a wpf project that has a code like this in my Button

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button myButton = new Button();
    myButton.Content = "Sample";
    grid1.Children.Add(myButton);   
}
```

And now i want when my new Button created, my form save the new button for show next time when my form loaded!
i hope understand my purpose.

Comment: Look for information about dynamic controls. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393116/dynamic-control-in-wpf). You want to create a data model and a dynamic UI for it using item controls & templates.

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xaml you can use a ItemsControl for that. The ItemsPanel of the ItemsControl will then be your Grid (which you already have) and the ItemTemplate will be a DataTemplate which contains your button style. To populate the ItemsControl you have to set the Items or ItemsSource property.
 [More info on ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

For saving the buttons you can use multipe things for example:

- A settings file ([User setting in WPF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickdanino/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf/))
- Any kind of temp file
- or even a DB if you aready have one in place

Having a look at data binding will also help you: [Data Binding (WPF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf)

Comment: When using a Grid as ItemsPanel, you'll also need an ItemContainerStyle that sets the `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` property. You can't do that in the ItemTemplate. It may however be a lot easier to use a StackPanel as ItemsPanel, which is the default anyway.